# Facing issue in debugging the error related to serializeUser and deserializeUser

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Every time I am running nodemon my localhost responds as expected but when I change the route it shows a stack trace not quite sure why this is happening every time I change the route.
When I change a line in my code then the page loads in the browser and when I change the route I encounter the same issue my browser doesn't respond.

Here is the stack trace:

```
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  }
},
Query: [Function (anonymous)] {
  base: {
    toConstructor: [Function: toConstructor],
    setOptions: [Function (anonymous)],
    collection: [Function: collection],
    collation: [Function (anonymous)],
    '$where': [Function (anonymous)],
    where: [Function (anonymous)],
    equals: [Function: equals],
    eq: [Function: eq],
    or: [Function: or],
    nor: [Function: nor],
    and: [Function: and],
    gt: [Function (anonymous)],
    gte: [Function (anonymous)],
    lt: [Function (anonymous)],
    lte: [Function (anonymous)],
    ne: [Function (anonymous)],
    in: [Function (anonymous)],
    nin: [Function (anonymous)],
    all: [Function (anonymous)],
    regex: [Function (anonymous)],
    size: [Function (anonymous)],
    maxDistance: [Function (anonymous)],
    minDistance: [Function (anonymous)],
    mod: [Function (anonymous)],
    exists: [Function (anonymous)],
    elemMatch: [Function (anonymous)],
    within: [Function: within],
    box: [Function (anonymous)],
    polygon: [Function (anonymous)],
    circle: [Function (anonymous)],
    near: [Function: near],
    intersects: [Function: intersects],
    geometry: [Function: geometry],
    select: [Function: select],
    slice: [Function (anonymous)],
    sort: [Function (anonymous)],
    limit: [Function (anonymous)],
    skip: [Function (anonymous)],
    batchSize: [Function (anonymous)],
    comment: [Function (anonymous)],
    maxTimeMS: [Function (anonymous)],
    maxTime: [Function (anonymous)],
    hint: [Function (anonymous)],
    j: [Function: j],
    slaveOk: [Function (anonymous)],
    setReadPreference: [Function (anonymous)],
    read: [Function (anonymous)],
    r: [Function (anonymous)],
    readConcern: [Function (anonymous)],
    tailable: [Function (anonymous)],
    w: [Function: writeConcern],
    writeConcern: [Function: writeConcern],
    wTimeout: [Function: wtimeout],
    wtimeout: [Function: wtimeout],
    merge: [Function (anonymous)],
    find: [Function (anonymous)],
    _find: [AsyncFunction: _find],
    cursor: [Function (anonymous)],
    findOne: [Function (anonymous)],
    _findOne: [AsyncFunction: _findOne],
    count: [Function (anonymous)],
    _count: [AsyncFunction: _count],
    distinct: [Function (anonymous)],
    _distinct: [AsyncFunction: _distinct],
    updateMany: [Function: updateMany],
    _updateMany: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    updateOne: [Function: updateOne],
    _updateOne: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    replaceOne: [Function: replaceOne],
    _replaceOne: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    deleteOne: [Function (anonymous)],
    _deleteOne: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    deleteMany: [Function (anonymous)],
    _deleteMany: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    findOneAndUpdate: [Function (anonymous)],
    _findOneAndUpdate: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    findOneAndDelete: [Function (anonymous)],
    findOneAndRemove: [Function (anonymous)],
    _findOneAndRemove: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    setTraceFunction: [Function (anonymous)],
    exec: [AsyncFunction: exec],
    then: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    selected: [Function: selected],
    selectedInclusively: [Function: selectedInclusively],
    selectedExclusively: [Function: selectedExclusively],
    _mergeUpdate: [Function (anonymous)],
    _optionsForExec: [Function (anonymous)],
    _fieldsForExec: [Function (anonymous)],
    _updateForExec: [Function (anonymous)],
    _ensurePath: [Function (anonymous)],
    _validate: [Function (anonymous)]
  }
},
'$init': Promise { undefined, catch: [Function (anonymous)] },
'$caught': true,
[Symbol(mongoose#Model)]: true
```

}
}

Node.js v18.17.1
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

I have disabled authentication and tried still the same issue persists

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
  require("dotenv").config();
}

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const route = require("./routes/items");
const path = require("path");
const ejsMate = require("ejs-mate");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const methodOverride = require("method-override");
const session = require("express-session");
const flash = require("connect-flash");
const passport = require("passport");
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local");
const User = require("./models/user");
const route2 = require("./routes/users");

mongoose
  .connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/e-auction")
  .then(() => console.log("MONGODB CONNECTED"))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

const secretConfig = {
  secret: "thishouldbeabettersecret",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: {
    // secure: true,
    expires: Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
  },
};
app.use(flash());
app.use(session(secretConfig));


app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());



app.use(methodOverride("_method"));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.engine("ejs", ejsMate);
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));


app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.success = req.flash("success");
  res.locals.error = req.flash("error");
  res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
  next();
});



app.use("/", route);
app.use("/", route2);




app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  const { status = 500, message = "sorry something went wrong" } = err;
  res.status(status).render("error.ejs", { message });
});


app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Listening on port 3000...........");
});
```

this is my app.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const Product = require('../models/items')
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const name = "Home";
  const products = await Product.find();
  res.render("home.ejs", { name, products });
});


router.get("/new", (req, res) => {
  const name = "New";
  res.render("new.ejs", { name });
});

router.get("/:id/edit", async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const product = await Product.findById(id);
  const name = product.name;
  res.render("edit.ejs", { product, name });
});

router.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const product = await Product.findById(id);
  const name = product.name;
  res.render("about.ejs", { product, name });
});

router.put("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const product = await Product.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body, { new: true });
  product.save();
  res.redirect(`/${product.id}`);
});

router.post("/new", async (req, res) => {
  const body = req.body;
  await new Product(body).save();
  res.redirect("/");
});


router.delete('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const {id} = req.params;
    await Product.findByIdAndDelete(id);
    res.redirect('/');
})

module.exports = router;
```

this is my products route in the file items.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require("passport");
const User = require("../models/user");


router.get("/register", (req, res) => {
  const name = "Register";
  res.render("user/register.ejs", { name });
});

router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { username, email, password } = req.body;
    const user = await new User({ email, username });
    const registeredUser = await User.register(user, password);
    req.login(registeredUser, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      res.redirect("/");
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.redirect("/register");
  }
});


router.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  const name = "Login";
  res.render("user/login.ejs", { name });
});


router.post(
  "/login",
  passport.authenticate("local", {
    failureFlash: false,
    failureRedirect: "/login",
  }),
  (req, res) => {
    res.redirect("/");
  }
);

router.get("/logout", (req, res, next) => {
  req.logOut((err) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    res.redirect("/");
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

this is my user.js route file for authentication.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const productSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    basePrice: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    image: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

this is my model for products in items.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

this is my model for users in users.js

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).